# decimal.InvalidOperation error when rounding values in Series

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, decimal, rounding

Series I'm working with:

```
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal, BasicContext

df = pd.Series([14978.22,
16025.429160000002,
209.97803999999996,
618.20369,
605.607,
1431.0916,
30.53575,
23.77272,
404.79368999999997,
55580.152319999994
])
df2 = df.apply(str).apply(Decimal, context=BasicContext)
```

I'd like to round all the values in df to 5 digits using "ROUND_HALF_UP" (which is the rounding used for BasicContext). So, I do this:

```
df2.apply(round, ndigits=5)
```

However, this throws an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       df2.apply(round, ndigits=5)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
>   line 3194, in apply
>       mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
>
> File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1472, in
>   pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
>   line 3181, in 
>       f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwds)
>
> InvalidOperation: class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'

However, rounding to 4 digits works:

```
df2.apply(round, ndigits=4)
```

Why is this happening and how do I work around this?

Comment: `round` applied to a `Decimal` object requires that the current Decimal context has sufficient precision to represent the result. The `BasicContext` you're using has a precision of 9, but `16025.429160000002` rounded to 5 places after the point requires 10 significant digits to represent.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, any chance you could promote that comment to an answer?

Comment: @Jagerber48 Sorry, I don't have a lot of cycles available for Stack Overflow answers these days. But you should feel free to use the content of that comment in your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried catching the `decimal.InvalidOperation` exception? You should have a `try` and `except`.

```
try:
    # your code 
except DecimalException as e:
    print(e)
```